# I keep getting a TypeError while trying to fulfil my Promise

Tags: javascript

I'm using a weather API to retrieve data from a location and display it on a page. For the most part the solution works; however when I chain the `.then` methods I get a TypeError saying `"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'main')"`

```
fetch(
  `https://api.openweathermap.org/`,
  { mode: "cors" }
)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((response) => {
    // Displays current city
    city.textContent = response.name;
  })
  .then((response) => {
    // Displays current temperature
    temp.textContent = `${Math.trunc(response.main.temp)}°`;
  })
  .then((response) => {
    // Displays how much humidity
    humidity.textContent = `Humidity: ${response.main.humidity}%`;
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

There's a few more lines of code but I trimmed it down for readability sake.

**What I've Tried**

I've put everything inside a single `.then` method and the solution works fine. But I don't like how that looks so I spread it out to multiple `.then` methods and for some reason it turns `main` inside the `response.json` undefined so I no longer have access to that information.

Comment: The second `then` doesn't `return` anything, so the next `then` doesn't get anything. There's no need to break this into *this* many separate `then`s.

Comment: Can't you just write a single callback function that does all of your displays and then write .then((response) => { callback(response) } ?

Comment: @Emilien thank you for this idea. I did that and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In the first `.then(...)` you return the response as `return response.json();` so then, the second `.then(...)` will take it as an input.

The second  `.then(...)` returns `null`, so then the third `.then(...)`  will have null in the `response` argument.

To fix it, return the response you want to get passed down.

```js
.then((response) => {
    ...
    return response;
  })
```

Comment: The second `.then(...)` returns *`undefined`*…

Comment: Potato potahto, it's a void function, but yes, you are right. Either way irrelevant.

Comment: @Davo thank you for this solution it worked perfectly. I forgot that I had to return response every time.